# Interpretation of @ in a string argument to Matlab's quad

Tags: matlab

One of my students made the following simple error:

```
f = '@(x)sqrt(1-x^2)';    
quad(f,0,1)
```

which led to a very unexpected (to me) result:

```
ans =

        0 + 1.7119i
```

Presumably `@` is getting interpreted as some complex function, but which?

Comment: Are you sure the workspace was clear before running this? I only get errors running those two lines (in 2015b)

Comment: Same here in R2016b: `quad(f,0,1)` gives `The integrand function must return an output vector of the same length as the input vector.`

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce it at home myself, I'll have to double-check next Tuesday.